# Message received from Arduino showing up as boxed question marks.

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project that involves communication between an Android Uno and an Android phone. The phone sends a request signal "*" that once received, the Arduino sends random integers in a loop. Right now, the Android device is receiving the message but it is showing up as boxed question marks, and not receiving all of the messages. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int RX_PIN = 0;
const int TX_PIN = 1;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX_PIN, TX_PIN); 

char commandChar;
void setup (){
    bluetooth.begin (9600);
    Serial.begin(38400);

}
void loop () {
    if(bluetooth.available()){
        commandChar = bluetooth.read();
        switch(commandChar){
            case '*':
            Serial.println("Got the request code");
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                bluetooth.print(random(21));
            }
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Android code:

```
public void run() {
    initializeConnection();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int bytes;
    // Keep looping to listen for received messages
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);//read bytes from input buffer
            String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            Log.e("Received Message: ", readMessage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void initializeConnection() {
    try {
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(mmOutStream, true);
        out.println("*");
        out.flush();
    }catch (NullPointerException NPE) {

    }
}
```

Console output:

```
08-13 19:02:46.546 4019-4128/? E/Received Message:: �
08-13 19:02:46.596 4019-4128/? E/Received Message:: ����
```

Comment: Bluetooth is finicky. Can you include the name of the bluetooth module you're using?

Comment: Yes. It is HC-05 bluetooth module. The brand is DSD TECH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think I spot the problem. Random numbers are being sent from the arduino to the app, and the app is logging these bytes as ascii literals. Instead of sending random numbers, try sending well-formed ascii (visual characters).

You can send the hex bytes [0x68,0x65,0x6c,0x6c,0x6f] for "hello", or use [SoftwareSerialPrint](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialPrint)'s built-in HEX option.

So change it to this, see if that works.

`bluetooth.print(random(21), HEX);`

Edit:

Let's try this on the app side instead. This will convert the received bytes into a hexadecimal string representation so we can see it in ascii properly.

```
   bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);//read bytes from input buffer
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes * 2);
   for(byte b: buffer)
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
   Log.e("Received Message: ", sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this.

Comment: So it still prints out the boxed question marks unfortunately.

Comment: Added some changes

Comment: is the variable 'bytes' in your second solution still the int value i had before? It won't let me do bytes.length, and for(byte b: bytes)

Comment: whoops; try now

Comment: So this is the output that I received:E/Received Message:: fa000000000...(continued for much longer)

Comment: 510 zeros after the 'a' to be precise.

Comment: Are you still able to help me @Steven Huang?

Comment: Perhaps the baud rate for the HC-05 software serial is incorrect? It seems 38400 is its default baud rate; maybe you've switched your hardware serial and bluetooth serial baud rates around?

Comment: Ok I will try switching them.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I switched them around, the data did not get sent at all to the android phone.

Comment: Maybe try connecting hc-05 txrx into the uno's hardware txrx and use Serial.println instead of software serial. And the default is indeed 9600, not 38400.

Comment: So currently I did have the hc-05 txrx connected to the uno's hardware rxtx (tx goes to rx, and vice versa), and i also did try the Serial.println as a 'log' system for debugging purposes that gave an output on the Serial Monitor but not actually send data to the phone.

Comment: OMG! It worked! Thank you sooo much!!!! I changed the 38400 on the Serial to 9600 this time like you suggested and it worked! I cannot thank you enough for your persistent willingness to help me. You have truly saved my project. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! And you'll get the hang of this in no time; persistence is key :). I also looked into it again (since there's no reason why hardware uart works and software doesn't) and the reason it doesn't work is because you told bluetooth software serial to use the same pins (0, 1) as the hardware serial. So if you use any other digital pin on the uno (like pins 8, 9), it should work!

Comment: Hey Steven Huang, I am approached with a new problem which I have been trying to tackle for the last couple days. Could you take a look at my post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750069/arduino-not-sending-integers-properly