# Arduino not sending integers properly

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to send integers 0 through 10 from my Arduino Uno to my Android device. However, the Arduino is not sending the integers separately, but rather it is sending it as a cluster (sometimes 2 at a time). I want to be able to send an integer every 5 milliseconds and not delay any longer than that. Any ideas?

Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int RX_PIN = 8;
const int TX_PIN = 9;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX_PIN, TX_PIN); 
char commandChar;

void setup (){
    bluetooth.begin (9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop () {
    if(bluetooth.available()){
        commandChar = bluetooth.read();
        switch(commandChar){
            case '*':
            for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                bluetooth.print(i);
                delay(5);
            }
        break;
       }
    }   
 }
```

Android code:

```
public void run() {
    initializeConnection();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
    while (true) {
        try {
            if(mmSocket!=null) {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.e("Received Message ", readMessage);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR ", "reading from btInputStream");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Android Monitor/Console output:

```
08-18 19:46:32.319 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 0
08-18 19:46:32.324 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 1
08-18 19:46:32.324 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 23
08-18 19:46:32.324 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 4
08-18 19:46:32.379 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 56
08-18 19:46:32.379 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 78
08-18 19:46:32.379 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 91
08-18 19:46:32.384 6720-6749/? E/Received Message: 0
```

Comment: What is `mmInStream` in your Android code?

Comment: mmInStream is the Input Stream of the bluetooth socket between the arduino and the android phone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the serial communication is working as stream (not datagram) and isn't keeping any data boundary.

Therefore, it seems you should add data separator (for example: newline) to your sending data and process it in the receiver (for example: use `BufferedReader`) to keep the data boundary.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam.C you've asked me to take a look at this, and this answer is spot on. GL on your project!